# JMenuItem exit doesn't exit

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have simple Java [GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb0jC.png), on click the JMenuItem 'Exit' on the menu 'File' doesn't exit the GUI. I want to set 'confirm warning window' before user closes the GUI. so far I've tried, please give me directions; Thanks.

the code:

```
private void initialize() {
        frmScms = new JFrame();
        frmScms.setTitle("SCMS");
        frmScms.setBounds(100, 100, 1080, 684);
        frmScms.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmScms.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.setBounds(0, 0, 1064, 21);
        frmScms.getContentPane().add(menuBar);

        JMenu menuF = new JMenu("File");
        menuF.add("New");
        menuF.add("Open");
        menuF.add("Save");
        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        menuF.add(exit);

        JMenu menuS = new JMenu("Edit");
        menuS.add("Cut");
        menuS.add("Copy");
        menuS.add("Paste");
        menuS.add("Delete");
        JMenu menuT = new JMenu("Help");
        menuT.add("Help Contents");
        menuT.add("Search");
        menuT.add("About SCMS");

        menuBar.add(menuF);
        menuBar.add(menuS);
        menuBar.add(menuT);

        class exitAction implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frmScms, "Are you sure you want to close the application?", "Please Confirm-?",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                    frmScms.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        }
        exit.addActionListener(new exitAction());

    }
```

On the other hand; The code below it closes the GUI;

```
class exitAction implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
exit.addActionListener(new exitAction());
```

Comment: What is the javadoc of setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE), that you call when the user has confirmed? Does it do the same thing as System.exit(), which is what you want to do?

Comment: Thanks @JB Nizet, instead of "setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);" have put "System.exit(0);" worked, thank you so much!

Comment: @Java.beginner, your code will only work if the user clicks on the exit menu. You may also want to check out [Closing an Application](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/). It will allow the user to close the frame when the click on the "X" button of the window, or the Exit menu item.

Comment: Thanks @camickr for the directions, now I've added code to the existing one and it works good, thanks '  frmScms.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
  frmScms.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
   public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
          JFrame frame = (JFrame)e.getSource();
          int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Are you sure you want to close the application?", "Please Confirm",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
          if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
              frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      }
  });'

Answer (score 1):

When you use `setDefaultCloseOperation`, your program will exit only when the user clicks on the cross at the top of the window. This is because `setDefaultCloseOperation()` just tells the program what to do when the user tries to exit. On the other hand, `System.exit(0)` forces the program to exit then and there. So if you want to close the program, use `System.exit(0);`

Cheers.